# Laravel Material Design theme strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, laravel, material-design

Recently I installed the [Laravel Material Design](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-laravel) theme. I managed to setup everything nicely, and everything was working until I added some `vue.js templates`. When I imported my `app.js` file, where my templates are loaded, some of the features of the theme just stopped working, and I have no idea why. This is my `app.js` file:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('users-component', require('./components/UsersComponent').default);
Vue.component('blogs-component', require('./components/BlogsComponent').default);
Vue.component('news-component', require('./components/NewsComponent').default);
Vue.component('paginator', require('./components/Paginator.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue',
});
```

So, I compile the file, and I import it at the bottom of my `app.blade.php` layout:

```
....
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

When I load my page, my `vue.js templates` are working correctly. The problem is, the theme navigation just stops working, and I can't click the navigation list:

[image]

I begin to investigate, and in the browser console, I see the following errors:

[image]

When I remove the `app.js` file from my layout, the navigation starts working again, and I don't see any errors in the console, but of course, my `vue.js templates` are not working. This is full list of imported scripts in my layout:

```
<!--   Core JS Files   -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/core/bootstrap-material-design.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Plugin for the momentJs  -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/plugins/moment.min.js"></script>
<!--  Plugin for Sweet Alert -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/plugins/sweetalert2.js"></script>
<!-- Forms Validations Plugin -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/plugins/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<!-- Plugin for the Wizard, full documentation here: https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/plugins/jquery.bootstrap-wizard.js"></script>
<!--    Plugin for Select, full documentation here: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/plugins/bootstrap-selectpicker.js"></script>
<!--  Plugin for the DateTimePicker, full documentation here: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<!--  DataTables.net Plugin, full documentation here: https://datatables.net/  -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/plugins/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<!--    Plugin for Tags, full documentation here: https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinputs  -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/plugins/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
<!-- Plugin for Fileupload, full documentation here: http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/plugins/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--  Full Calendar Plugin, full documentation here: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar    -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/plugins/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<!-- Vector Map plugin, full documentation here: http://jvectormap.com/documentation/ -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/plugins/jquery-jvectormap.js"></script>
<!--  Plugin for the Sliders, full documentation here: http://refreshless.com/nouislider/ -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/plugins/nouislider.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include a polyfill for ES6 Promises (optional) for IE11, UC Browser and Android browser support SweetAlert -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.4.1/core.js"></script>
<!-- Library for dynamically adding elements -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/plugins/arrive.min.js"></script>
<!-- Chartist JS -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/plugins/chartist.min.js"></script>
<!--  Notifications Plugin    -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/plugins/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>
<!-- Control Center for Material Dashboard: parallax effects, scripts for the example pages etc -->
<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/material-dashboard.js?v=2.1.1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
@stack('js')

@if(isset($scripts))
    @foreach($scripts as $key => $value)
        <script src="{{ asset($value)}}"></script>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

What seems to be the problem here. Any help appreciated.

UPDATE:

This is the bootsrtap.js:

```
window._ = require('lodash');

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Comment: Show us your js/bootstrap.js code please

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: You load jQuery and Popper 2 times.
And maybe bootstrap conflicts with bootstrap-material-design.
Trying to compile (npm run dev) after deleting the contents of bootstrap.js

Comment: Or without require('./bootstrap'); in app.js